# All my objects move together as if they are linked

Tags: objects, linked-data

I have this problem: all of my objects are linked, I don't know what I did for that to happen. Even if I add an object and I move another, it will move the object I've just inserted.

Here's my problem in video: https://kapwi.ng/c/edUbpldI

Comment: Hello :). This looks like you enabled Proportional Editing (Shortcut: **O** to disable).

Comment: Thank you very much @JachymMichal, it worked!

Comment: Literally the same issue haha. I love finding out that I'm an idiot. Thanks, @jachymmichal!!!

Comment: @JunoSprite No problem, this happens to everybody at some point :)). Good luck with your project :)